# Issue with ajax update url

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on a drawer cart populated via ajax for a shopify site. There's also a quantity field with plus and minus buttons within this cart. 
This is the code for the plus button:

```
// This button will increment the value
$('.ajax-cart-form').on("click",'.qtyplus.qtyplus-2', function(){
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[id='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        // Increment
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
    var currentVal2 = parseInt($('input[id='+fieldName+']').val());
    var currentProd = $('input[id='+fieldName+']').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/cart/update.js',
  data: { updates: { currentProd : currentVal2 }},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/cart.js',
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() {
          $.getJSON(_config.shopifyAjaxCartURL, function(cart) {
            $('.drawer-subtotal').remove();
            $('.ajax-subtotal').css('display','none');
            $(function(index, cartItem) {
                  var line2= index +1;
                  var cents2 = "";

          if (cart.original_total_price % 100 < 10) {
          cents2 = "0";
          }
          var price2 = parseInt(cart.original_total_price/100) + "." + cents2 + cart.original_total_price % 100;
            $('.ajax-subtotal2').append("<div class='drawer-subtotal'><h3>Subtotal <span class='money'>£"+ price2 +" GBP</span></h3></div>");
            });
              $('#item_count').text(currentVal2);
      });
    }
    });
  }
});
});
```

As you can see I'm getting the value of the quantity field to update the quantity in the ajax post request via the variable currentVal2. This works fine. I'm also getting the product ID via the id of the input field.
I've tried

```
alert(currentProd);
```

and this outputs the ID correctly. However, when I'm trying to use this variable in the update function like this

```
 data: { updates: { currentProd : currentVal2 }},
```

I'm getting the error that update.js is not found so I'm assuming it's not pulling in the Product ID correctly.

If instead I try

```
data: { updates: { 35450129542: currentVal2 }},
```

so input the product ID directly it works.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Marial, Looks like the location of update.js file is not correct. url: '/cart/update.js', how about try with absolute url and see if that works.

Comment: if you are trying to use a dynamic property name (`currentProd`) then you cannot set the parameter inline. Instead use bracket notation. For example:  `var myData = { updates : {} };  myData.updates[currentProd] = currentVal2;`  and later in the $.ajax-parameters: `... url: '/cart/update.js', data: myData, dataType: 'json', ...`

Comment: I'm just saying if you do this: `{ currentProd : currentVal2 }` then currentProd will always be interpreted as a property name (string), identical to `{ "currentProd" : currentVal2 }`. (take note of the quotes)

Comment: @ippi thanks! got it working like this   data: { updates: { [currentProd] : currentVal2 }}

Comment: Oh cool. Now I learned something as well.